# System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: when calling docusign api

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am getting the following error when calling the Docusign API in a plugin running on CRM Online.

System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException:

Type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[DocuSignIntegration.Plugins.DocuSignAPI.Envelope]' 
cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, 
and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute 
attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the 
CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for 
other supported types.

Here's the code:

```
        EnvelopeInformation envelopeInfo = new EnvelopeInformation();
        envelopeInfo.AccountId = _accountId;
        envelopeInfo.Subject = "My Subject";
        envelopeInfo.EmailBlurb = "My email blurb.";

        tracing.Trace("Enter using...");
        using (var scope = new System.ServiceModel.OperationContextScope(_apiClient.InnerChannel))
        {
            tracing.Trace("httpRequestProperty");
```

It throws the error on the "using (var scope...") line.

The help I find online suggests changes to the service, which of course doesn't help solve this. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There's most likely a problem with the DataContract you're configuring, as I'm able to make SOAP API calls just fine using the [DocuSign SOAP SDK up on GitHub](https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK).  That project might be helpful for you as you can use that as an example (since it works out of the box) and has sample projects for `.NET`, `Java`, `PHP`, `Salesforce`, and `Ruby`.

Use that project to compare how the ServiceModel and DataContracts are setup too see where yours might be off.  I would also recommend wrapping your code in a `try-catch` block to get more information on the error.  Something like:

```
try
    {
        EnvelopeInformation envelopeInfo = new EnvelopeInformation();
        envelopeInfo.AccountId = _accountId;
        envelopeInfo.Subject = "My Subject";
        envelopeInfo.EmailBlurb = "My email blurb.";

        tracing.Trace("Enter using...");
        using (var scope = new System.ServiceModel.OperationContextScope(_apiClient.InnerChannel))
        {
            tracing.Trace("httpRequestProperty");

            // ... remaining code ...
        }
    }

    // Catch the InvalidDataContractException here. 
    catch(InvalidDataContractException iExc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have an invalid data contract: ");
        Console.WriteLine(iExc.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
      catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString() );
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```